Equivalence description for compact object in category theory

Definition An object $c$ in category $C$ is called compact if the functor $\text{Hom}(c,\_):C\rightarrow \text{SETS}$ preserves filtered colimits. i.e. $$\text{Hom}(c,\text{colim}_{i\in I}c_i)=\text{colim}_{i\in I}\text{Hom}(c,c_i)$$

One can show that if the category $C$ satifies that $\forall I$ filtered the functor $\text{colim}:\text{Func}(I,C)\rightarrow C,F\mapsto \text{colim}_iF(i)$ perserves finite limits and finite limits exisits in $C$, then compactness can be replaced by the following weaker condition:

$\forall f:c\rightarrow \text{colim}_{i\in I}c_i,\exists i$ and morphism $f_i:c\rightarrow c_i$ such that $f$ factorizes over $c_i$
$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.1em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& c_i\\
& \diaguparrow{f_i} @VVp_iV \\
c @>>f> \text{colim}_ic_i
\end{CD}$$
where $p_i$ is the defining morphsim for $\text{colim}_ic_i$.

My main issue is to prove the injectivity of the isomorphism $\text{Hom}(c,\text{colim}_{i\in I}c_i)\cong\text{colim}_{i\in I}\text{Hom}(c,c_i)$ while assuming the weaker condition.

Let us define the map $$\begin{align*}
\text{colim}_{i\in I}\text{Hom}(c,c_i)&\rightarrow \text{Hom}(c,\text{colim}_{i\in I}c_i)\\
f_i&\mapsto p_i\circ f_i
\end{align*}
$$
In order to show injectivity, we pick $f_i:c\rightarrow c_i,f_j:c\rightarrow c_j$ such that $p_i\circ f_i=p_j\circ f_j$. Because $I$ is filtered, $\exists k\in I$ such that $g_1:i\rightarrow k$ and $g_2:j\rightarrow k$ then we can get $p_k\circ c_{g_1}\circ f_i=p_k\circ c_{g_2}\circ f_j$ and we still need to show $ c_{g_1}\circ f_i= c_{g_2}\circ f_j$. But I do not know how to continue since $p_k$ is not necessarily monomorphism.

I think if we can find another cointial object $c_w$ for $c_i$ and $c_j$ for some $w\in I$ then we are done. My guess is since in the assumption finite limits exist, maybe we can show pullback of $c_i\rightarrow c_k,c_j\rightarrow c_k$ exists in $C$ but I still have some issue since this pullback does not necessarily lie in the (essential) image of the functor $c:I\rightarrow C,i\mapsto c_i$.

I assume your category has filtered colimits, otherwise the colim functor you write down is not well-defined (2nd paragraph).

Yes I assume that filtered colimits exist.

Take two elements with the same image under $\mathrm{colim}_i \hom(c,c_i) \to \hom(c,\mathrm{colim}_i c_i)$. Since the colimit is filtered, they come from two morphisms $f,g : c \rightrightarrows c_0$ for some suitable $0 \in I$. We need to show that there is some $n \geq 0$ such that $u_n f = u_n g$, where $u_n : c_0 \to c_n$ is the transition morphism. Our assumption is $u_\infty f = u_\infty g$, where $u_\infty : c_0 \to \mathrm{colim}_i c_i$ is the inclusion into the colimit.
Let $d_n := \mathrm{eq}(u_n f, u_n g)$. This is a subobject of $c$, and clearly $n \leq m \implies d_n \subseteq d_{m}$ as subobjects. Consider the filtered colimit $d_\infty := \mathrm{colim}_n d_n$ (indexed by all $n \geq 0$ in $I$). Since by assumption filtered colimits commute with equalizers, $d_\infty \cong \mathrm{eq}(\mathrm{colim}_n u_n f,\mathrm{colim}_n u_n g) \cong \mathrm{eq}(u_\infty f, u_\infty g) \cong c$. By assumption, the isomorphism $c \to d_\infty$ factors over some $d_n \to d_\infty$. But then $d_n = c$ (as subobjects), which means $u_n f = u_n g$.

Sehr geehrter Dr.Brandenburg, thank you for your nice answer. Sorry there is still some questions that I do not understand. Q1: in the second last column I do not understand that why $c\rightarrow d_{\infty}$ has to factor over some $d_n$. Q2: You used in your proof $\leq$ very often, is it true that in any filtered category there is a natural partial order? Of course that does not effect me from understanding your proof since one can replace $\leq$ by morphism in $I$. Q3: I am not sure but I think in your proof you assume that every object in $C$ has a set structure. Mit freundlichen Grüßen


This is precisely the assumption on $c$. 2) Filtered colimits can always be replaced by colimits indexed by filtered partial orders. But yeah we don't need that there. Sorry for the confusion. Just take morphisms in the indices. 3) No. If it's because of the $\subseteq$, see Mac Lane or the nlab for the definition of the partial order on $Sub(c)$.


@downvoter: what can I improve?
